# NestJS swagger (with plugin) doesn't pickup DTOs when pipe operator is used

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I'm using nestjs and swagger plugin with cli configuration.
All of my DTOs and their attributes are picked up fine until I refer to any dto as below.

```
  data?:
   GetAbcResponseDto
   | GetXycResponseDto
```

So when the pipe operator is present, the Dto objects are not picked up as schema objects and not resolved with reference paths.

is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with Typescript's reflection API. This is essentially a union type, could be typed as `Union<GetAbcReponseDto, GetXycResponseDto>`. Typescript doesn't correctly reflect generics, and because of that Nest can't read what the metadata type is, and correctly access it for the pipe. If you need to be able to handle two types like this, your best bet would be to use a custom pipe.